# Which Ad Blocker for Firefox best meets these common requirements?

Tags: firefox, ad-blocker

I used Adblock Plus for a few years, and now I'm using uBlock since a month ago, but I can still see some ads (although they are relatively rare).

I have never used Adguard, but I've heard that it's good. But how good exactly compared to the previous two? I believe that there is a "premium version" which isn't free - I would not mind paying if it is truly better than Adblock Plus and uBlock.

Note that I have 16 GB of RAM, so RAM consumption is not a problem.

The "best" ad blocker is defined as:

1. The ad blocker which can block the most ads.
2. The ad blocker which can block ads as quickly as possible, without increasing too much the time it takes to load the pages.
3. The ad blocker which doesn't cause problems like making Firefox crash (I'm not sure if any of them do cause Firefox to crash, but my Firefox crashes relatively often).

But item #1 is the most important: I want to see as few ads as possible.

Answer (score 4):

At this time, [uBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/ublock/) will meet your requirements the best.

uBlock matches your **primary requirement** of "The ad blocker which can block the most ads" very well.  It is specifically designed to handle very large blocking lists with minimal impact.

Almost any ad blocking program will reduce the amount of time it takes to load a page, because it will block calls to many ads and trackers (sometimes more than 50% of what a page loads).

All the ad blockers you mentioned are considered stable, so none should make Firefox crash.  Adblock Plus is known to use up massive amounts of memory in some extreme cases.

Although I do not recommend Adblock Plus at all, at this time [Adblock Edge](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/adblock-edge/) (based on much of the same code, but without all the bloat and [questionable "features"](https://superuser.com/questions/626577/adblock-plus-doesnt-block-google-ads-how-to-enable)) has a **more refined user interface** than uBlock.  It allows creating groups of custom filters via the GUI, which can significantly reduce the amount of effort required for maintenance.

Comment: Note that [AdBlock Edge](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-edge/) "*will be discontinued on June 2015 in favor of uBlock, a general purpose blocker, that not only outperforms Adblock Edge but is also available on other browsers and, of course, without Acceptable Ads Whitelist*".

Comment: That is what the developer posted for now.  But Adblock Edge currently has about 8 million downloads and is completely open-source with an open MPL license, so it is very likely someone will want to continue it or create something similar.